# Increase multiple values in lua with one line

Tags: lua

So I was doing work in lua to make an object that essentially controlled and moved subobjects, and I was wondering if to reduce lines of code, I could increment multiple values in one statement. This is the entire function:

```
function ElephantEarC:SetOffset(x, y)
    local oiX, oiY -- Offset increase X/Y
    for i, stem in pairs(self.stems) do
        oiX, oiY = stem.low:GetOffset()
        oiX, oiY += x, y
    end
end
```

I was wondering if this line was valid:

```
oiX, oiY += x, y
```

A bit of information about this code

- self.stems is an array of the subobjects.
- GetOffset() returns two values-- x and y.
- Each 'stem' has three subobjects that are grouped together-- low, high and leaf (I just haven't written them in yet).

If anything else is vague, or this question's already been answered and I couldn't find it, please tell me...

Comment: What about checking yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think the syntax on the line with `+=` is valid. This will perform the additions on a single line correctly, though:

```
oiX, oiY = oiX+x, oiY+y
```